# Return value of a python function

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. Does all python function return some value? What will be the return value of the following function?

```
import math

def getQuadratic(a,b):
    square = a**2 + b**2
    squareRoot = math.sqrt(square)
    return squareRoot
print("The square root of the sum of the squares of 3 and 4 is:", getQuadratic(3,4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate the type returned by a Python function, you need to look at EVERY `return` statement, because each may return something different.  And if a function doesn't have an explicit `return`, there's an implied `return None` at the end.

In your case there's only one `return`, and it's easy to figure out what type it's returning.

Answer (score 0):

All python methods return something. Even if you have no return statement they will still return `None`.

```
def my_function():
    pass

print(my_function())
>>> None
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is definitely returning something. It's returning the value of the variable squareRoot. So when you're executing the print statement, the value that was returned is getting printed along with the string ahead of it.

Answer (score 0):

Python being a dynamically typed language, does not require you to define any type for variables or functions.

Everything in python is a first class object.

On your example:

```py
import math

def getQuadratic(a,b):
  square = a2 + b2  # is this square? a**2?
  squareRoot = math.sqrt(square)
  return squareRoot 

print("The square root of the sum of the squares of 3 and 4 is:", getQuadratic(3,4))
```

The variables `a`, `b` can take on any value.
Python does this by making everything a python object.
So, its easier to think of this way. `int` is your equivalent in `C`, however, in python it is treated as `class <int>`

However, static typing is now possible. It still depends on framework for static typing to be utilized. But your equivalent python program is interpreted as:

```py
import math

def getQuadratic(a:int,b:int) -> float:
  square = a2 + b2  # is this square? a**2?
  squareRoot = math.sqrt(square)
  return squareRoot 

print("The square root of the sum of the squares of 3 and 4 is:", getQuadratic(3,4))
```

TL;DR

In direct answer to your question,

- python does not require any types
- `a = 1` is valid.
- `a = 'SoF'` is still valid
- where `a` is a Python Object, and can be allocated to any other python object such as value, string, functions, or entire modules.
- It really doesn't make much difference in types. Its the way Python is designed.

Comment: While useful information, the question asked nothing about types